# Feedjira: Can you parse multiple URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, xml-parsing, feedjira

EDIT** *From [this post](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/issues/221) Jon mentions that he wants to move away from concurrency in 2.0, and instead a single url be passed and concurrency dealt with in the application, workers being the likely approach.*

I'm trying to parse multiple URLs with `FeedJira` (uses `farday` gem), but receiving an argument error. Has anyone had success parsing more than a single URL in the past? [The source](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/feedjira/feedjira/Feedjira/Feed#fetch_and_parse-class_method) for FeedJira::Feed states that it will return a single feed URL, or an array of feed URLs.

`.fetch_and_parse(urls, options = {}) ⇒ Object`

*script*

```
feed_urls = ["https://jobs.startupnorth.ca/jobs.rss", "https://jobs.startupnorth.ca/jobs.rss"]
feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_urls)
```

*error*

```
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/faraday-0.15.0/lib/faraday/utils.rb:277:in `URI'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/faraday-0.15.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:315:in `url_prefix='
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/faraday-0.15.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:80:in `initialize'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/faraday-0.15.0/lib/faraday.rb:70:in `new'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/faraday-0.15.0/lib/faraday.rb:70:in `new'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/feedjira-2.1.4/lib/feedjira/feed.rb:82:in `connection'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/feedjira-2.1.4/lib/feedjira/feed.rb:68:in `fetch_and_parse'
    from (irb):144
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/code/startupjobstoronto/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/taylorcooney/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: does it work for you with a single url of the above two?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss Yes, I can parse a variety of feeds using a single URL

Comment: you could use `map`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I appreciate the response but, that's not really my question here

Comment: Was just checking if that's an option. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method was changed in version 2.0.0. Make sure that you are using version < 2.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot @panic...I'll try to look around the github issues if there is any discussion around this. Feel free to link it below if you're familiar and I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: From [this post](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/issues/221) Jon mentions that he wants to move away from concurrency in 2.0, and instead a single url be passed and concurrency dealt with in the application, workers being the likely approach.